# Bootstrap navbar didn't collapse on Firefox & Chrome but worked fine on IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code. The navbar did collapse on IE but didn't on Firefox and Chrome. I host my web on google drive, is this a possible bug?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myCollapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
              <li><a href="index.html"><h4>Home</h4></a></li>
              <li><a href="Projects.html"><h4>Portfolio</h4></a></li>
              <li><a href="Trung Vo's Resume.pdf" target="blank"><h4>Resume</h4></a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Did you remember to include jQuery in your page? In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twernt/av8ofqed/), the menu is collapsing in both Firefox and Chrome for me.

Comment: I did include jQuery in my page. The problem is that when I tested offline on all the browsers, they all worked fine. But when I host on my gg drive, only IE had the navbar collapsed, while Firefox and Chrome didn't.

Comment: I think I know the problem, that is the IE only worked when I allowed blocked content being displayed. IE said it blocks page from running scripts and ActiveX controls. How can I fix this?